# Ainda é recomendado tratar o IE (Internet Explorer) nos testes de CrossBrowser?

Tags: navegador-de-internet, internet-explorer, ux, cross-browser

Hoje sabemos que 80% ou mais dos acessos aos sites são *mobile*, e que as tecnologias estão avançando cada vez mais nesse sentido como os **PWA** e o **AMP**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: http://zydigital.com.br/radar/dados-da-comscore-sobre-acessos-a-internet-destacam-o-mobile-apps-e-entretenimento/

Além disso, pensando em ***Graceful Degradation*** versus ***Progressive Enhancement***, até que ponto visando a **UX**, eu devo "prejudicar" a maioria dos usuários evitando novas tecnologias em prol de **5%** ou menos dos usuários que ainda usam **IE**?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: https://caniuse.com/usage-table

No Windows atual o **IE** não é o browser padrão, e no próximo Windows se quer ele vai existir... **Existe alguma razão para ainda testar no **IE**?**

Pensando em **UX**, é aconselhável fazer o usuário migrar para uma plataforma mais moderna deixando de dar suporte para as antigas?
 *(pratica aplicada pela própria MicroSoft)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dê suporte ao usuário, e não ao navegador.

É fato que a maioria dos acessos hoje se dá via mobile [(fonte)](https://gs.statcounter.com/platform-market-share/desktop-mobile/worldwide/#monthly-201910-201910-bar). Mas você deve analisar primariamente o público do seu site. A audiência é o que importa. É esperado que um site como Stack Overflow, direcionado para programadores, tenha mais acessos desktop com browsers de última geração. Mas também é esperado que um site de uma comunidade de tricô tenha browsers nem tão atualizados. E não só o exemplo clichê do tricô, mas também existem empresas em que o uso de Internet Explorer é mandatório [(exemplo)](https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2015/08/why-do-enterprises-still-use-internet-explorer/).

Para medir qual é o navegador, sistema operacional, e outras métricas do seu usuário, você pode usar uma ferramenta como o [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) em seu site.

Em uma perspectiva de experiência do usuário, existem algumas opções quando falamos em navegadores antigos, tendo em base as [heurísticas da usabilidade](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/):

1. Em hipótese alguma culpe o usuário. A culpa do navegador não ser suportado pelo seu site é sua e não do seu usuário. Ele pode estar usando Netscape 8, a culpa ainda é sua.
2. Apresente uma versão utilizável do seu site sem JavaScript ou CSS. Tenha certeza que é melhor que deixar seu usuário com uma página em branco (como é o caso de single-page applications que não conseguem carregar seu JS).
3. Mostre uma mensagem na página dizendo ao usuário que seu site parece ruim por conta do navegador não suportado. Uma mensagem, e não um modal, pois não queremos quebrar o fluxo.
4. Se uma parcela considerável dos seus acessos vem de navegadores não suportados, adicione o mínimo de CSS e JavaScript que seja suportado por esses navegadores para melhorar a experiência.

Answer (score 0):

Eu partiria para a comunicação oficial que o suporte iria acabar para este tipo de browser pois está sendo prejudicial para o restantes dos usuários e tornando mais caro sua manutenção. Obviamente esses 5% são financeiramente estratégicos para o negócio ? se não, manda ver na comunicação.

Em resumo, a partir do momento que o browser IE foi descontinuado, já **não é mais recomendado**. Faça grande uso de estratégias que propicie os usuários a migrarem de browser, mostre os benefícios.

Lembre-se que é comum essa prática, muitos desistiam de suportar versões antigas do Internet Explorer, cortando uma fatia significativa de possíveis consumidores. Isso acontece com os celulares Android, IOS e por ai vai.

Abraços!